# Ubuntu Gnome keyboard layout switch invokes blur event

Tags: javascript, html, ubuntu

I have an input field on my page. It has some `blur` listeners attached, that do some complex logic after user has finished input, involving some massive alterations of page content.

When user is in the middle of editing the text inside the input, they wants to switch their keyboard layout (aka input method) via `Alt+Shift` or `Super+Space`. And at this moment it goes wrong for Gnome users, because this is what happens:

1. User presses combination
2. Gnome window manager (or whatever) temporally receives focus to do its job and switch layouts
3. My input emits `blur` event, because browser's whole window loses focus
4. All of my complex logic occurs, because my app thinks that user has ended their edits
5. But user is in the middle of editing process, they just wanted to switch keyboard layouts!

How can I distinguish this temporal blur from normal one?

P.S. Using timeouts does not work in general because user can hold their `Super` key and keep scrolling through available layouts for seconds (or any other unlimited amount of time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually worked out a solution that is suitable for my case (see a caveat below). The idea is to check if the `document.activeElement` property contains my input that I am listening blur on:

```js
function handleBlur(ev) {
    if (document.activeElement === myInput) { return; }

    doComplexLogicToAlterPageContent();
}
```

**But** it has a false-positive case. This condition also prevents all the complex calculations from being done when user switches to another tab or another window. For my case it was ok, so when user returns to my tab, they can continue editing.